# Count IF process , what is wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, command

i m learning bash 
I need to count the proces on an IF and on ELSE.
But in the END of Program this  show me alway ZERO.
But if i put the echo  in if  show correctly.
What i going wrong  ? 
Thx

My Code

```
# CHEQUEA SI  EXISTE JSON2.ML - SI NO EXISTE REALIZA EL POST
acount=0
acounte=0
bcount=0
bcounte=0
api=APP_USR-1447105125686073-091812-eeceb6a719ab67de157c32d7c0d6dbc7-335445253




# Borra archivos con errores  
find -type f -name '*.ml' -size 0 | while read f; do rm "${f%.*}."* ; done
find -type f -name '*.ml' -exec grep -c -q '"Validation error","error"' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;
find -type f -name '*.ml' -exec grep -c -q 'invalid_token' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;
find -type f -name '*.ml' -exec grep -c -q 'access_token.invalid' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;
find -type f -name '*.ml' -exec grep -c -q 'body.invalid_field_types' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;
find -type f -name '*.ml' -exec grep -c -q 'item.price.invalid' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;
find -type f -name '*.ml' -exec grep -c -q 'FURY_SAVE_KVSAPI_ERROR' '{}' \; -exec rm '{}' \;


# Busca archivos .ml si no encuentra sube articulo JSON2
find . -type f -name '*.json2' | xargs bash -c 'for fname
do if [ ! -e ${fname}.ml ]
then curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @${fname} https://web/api > ${fname}.ml 
(( acount++ ))
echo $acount
else
(( acounte++ ))
fi

done

' bash

# Busca archivos .ml si no encuentra sube articulo JSON3
find . -type f -name '*.json3' | xargs bash -c 'for fname
do if [ ! -e ${fname}.ml ]
then curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @${fname} https://web/api > ${fname}.ml  
(( bcount++ ))
echo $bcount
else
(( bcounte++ ))
fi


done
echo  Total archivos JSON2 no subidos $acounte
echo  Total archivos JSON2 subidos $acount
echo  Total archivos JSON3 no subidos $bcounte
echo  Total archivos JSON3 subidos $bcount
tacounte=$(echo $acounte)
tacount=$(echo $acount)
tbcounte=$(echo $bcounte)
tbcount=$(echo $bcount)
' bash

echo  Total archivos JSON2 no subidos $tacounte
echo  Total archivos JSON2 subidos $tacount
echo  Total archivos JSON3 no subidos $tbcounte
echo  Total archivos JSON3 subidos $tbcount
```

This show

echo  Total archivos JSON2 no subidos $tacounte `0`

echo  Total archivos JSON2 subidos $tacount  `0`

echo  Total archivos JSON3 no subidos $tbcounte   `0`

echo  Total archivos JSON3 subidos $tbcount       `0`

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: sry i quit the tag!

Answer (score 1):

You have two different counters, which happened to have the same name. You have for instance `acount` in your parent process, which is initially set to 0 and never changed. This is what gets printed. Then you have an `acount` in each child process which is executed by the xargs command. This counter is incremented separately in each child process, but never printed.

You could move the printing of the counter into the child process, but since you may have (depending on the number of files involved) several child process, this does not guarantee you to really see a total count.

In your case, xargs is not the proper tool. As an alternative, you could instead pipe the output of your `find` into a `while read ....` loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "example"? Just do a `find .... | while read ...` for your counting, in the same way as you have already done in your script for removing the files with size zero.